# PowerShell not running all lines in Function

Tags: powershell

Below Function is not running the lines "If ($script:AADServersTable)" down... I have put a write-host and that is working, however the variables are not working below that

```
Function get-AADVariables 
{
    $script:AADServersTable = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]'
    $scriptBlockaadinstalled = {
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | 
    where name -eq "Microsoft Azure AD Connect synchronization services"  | select Name, Version}
    ##$scriptBlockaadinstalled = {hostname}

       Import-Module ActiveDirectory
        $servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingsystem -like "*server*" -and enabled -eq "true"' | Select-Object -Property Name -ExcludeProperty Release
             ## just a single invoke-command
        foreach ($server in $servers) {
        $aadinstalledresults = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server.name -ScriptBlock $scriptBlockaadinstalled ##-HideComputerName
        $aadinstalledresults = $aadinstalledresults.PSComputerName
         
            $script:AADServersTable.Add($aadinstalledresults)
               }
               If ($script:AADServersTable) {
               Write-Host 'working'
               $AADServers = ($script:AADServersTable | Group-Object -NoElement).Name | Get-Unique
               $AADServers = $AADServers -split "`n"
               $AADServer = $AADServers[0]
               $StandByAADServer = $AADServers[1]
               $SecondStandByAADServer = $AADServers[2]
               }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the variables are not working`?  Which lines/commands are not working? What result/error are you getting?

Comment: What is the result of ‘ ($script:AADServersTable | Group-Object -NoElement).Name | Get-Unique’

Comment: I get result from $script:AADServersTable.Add($aadinstalledresults) - So if I run $script:AADServersTable - I get servers in the list, however $AADServers and the rest down are all null. - So wired, because if I run the lines one by one with ISE it all works fine

Comment: Learn to properly indent your code. If you do, you'll find it much easier to trace through the flow of execution. What you have now is an indentation nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however currently I can see where it get stuck - if I run $AADServers = ($script:AADServersTable | Group-Object -NoElement).Name | Get-Unique in the function it does not set the variable, However if I use ISE and manually run the same thing it works...

Comment: Found a limitation with Function - Once I take the script out of a function it all works.